# Page Not Found after signInWithRedirect(), after deploying to firebase

Tags: angular, firebase-authentication

When served locally, the sign in and redirect both work, but when I deploy to firebase hosting, the redirect after sign-in stops working, instead giving me an error 404, no matter what route I try to navigate to. If I clear the url in the address bar and type in just the base url again, it works fine and I'm logged in

Login function from `auth.service.ts`

```ts
login() {
    let returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('returnUrl') || '/home';
    localStorage.setItem('returnUrl', returnUrl);


    this.afAuth.signInWithRedirect(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
  }
```

Auth guard:

```ts
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.auth.user$.subscribe(user => {
        if (user) {
          resolve(true);
        }
  
        else {          
          this.router.navigate(['/login'], );
          resolve(false);}
      });
  })
```

Login function that happens on click in the `login.component.ts`:

```ts
login() {
    this.auth.login()
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have Angular SPA application then check rewrites array in your firebase.json config. In this case when hosting on firebase you need to redirect all calls to index.html like this:

```
"hosting": {
  // ...

  "rewrites": [ {
    "source": "**",
    "destination": "/index.html"
  } ]
}
```